# how to add check box with enable or disable format in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Two database table

1-customer_table

```
customer_id                       customer_group
1                                  1,2,3
2                                   -
3                                  1,5,3,4
```

and second table

2-group

```
group_id                      group_name
1                                  A
2                                  B
3                                  C
4                                  D
5                                  E
```

i want to create code for add group in customer table with check box.

when we add group in customer id 1 the check boxes are show 1,2,3,4,5 where 1,2,3 are show with check box with checked or disable and rest only as check box....

`if($row['customer_group']=='')
 {
          $res = "SELECT grp_id, grp_name FROM grp_table";
         $result1 = mysql_query($res);
         while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
         {
         echo "<input name='group[]' id='group[]'  type='checkbox' value='$row1[grp_id]' />"."". $row1['grp_name']."&nbsp;" ;
         echo "<br>";       
         }
 }
 else
 {
         $res = "SELECT grp_id, grp_name FROM group_table";
         $result1 = mysql_query($res);

          $lst_rp = explode(',', $row['customer_group']);
             foreach($lst_rp as $rp_id) 
             {

             while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) 
                {
                    echo  $rp_id;
                 if($row1[grp_id]=='$rp_id')
                    {
                    echo "<input name='group[]' id='group[]'   checked='checked' type='checkbox' value='$row1[grp_id]' disabled />"."". $row1['sim_grp_name']."&nbsp;" ;
                    echo "<br>";        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    echo "<input name='group[]' id='group[]'   type='checkbox' value='$row1[grp_id]'   />"."". $row1['grp_name']."&nbsp;" ;
                    echo "<br>";    
                    }
                }

             }
    }


?>`

but i am unable to reach my final result.

Comment: If you take a look on your problem again, how would you describe it? Where is the road-block you hit?

Comment: use in_array instead of( == ) .I have to leave othre wise i will write the code for you .create an array of  customer_group field explode is by , and then at the timeing of applying loop on 2-group table check each group id as in_array(id,youraarayname)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you want to show the checkbox. You need to change line 4 to disabled="disabled"

```
   1  while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
   2  echo  $rp_id;
   3  if($row1[grp_id]=='$rp_id') {
   4  echo "<input name='group[]' id='group[]'   checked='checked' type='checkbox' value='$row1[grp_id]' disabled="disabled" />"."". $row1['sim_grp_name']."&nbsp;" ;
      echo "<br>"; } else {
      echo "<input name='group[]' id='group[]'   type='checkbox' value='$row1[grp_id]'   />"."". $row1['grp_name']."&nbsp;" ;
      echo "<br>";
       }
```